# How to order by distance with MongoDB and C# Linq driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have a query defined as follows:

```
var query = from h in myCollection.AsQueryable()
            where LinqToMongo.Inject(Query.Near("location", longitude, latitude, radius / 111.12))
            orderby ??????
            select h;
```

How can I get the results ordered by their distance from "latitude,longitude" to the "location" using Linq (and ordering it in MongoDB, not in memory)?

Comment: Look for moreLinq and download their orderby which allows you to specify each field automatically if the collection is strong typed.

Comment: afaik response should be already sorted that way - please check it

Comment: You are correct profesor79, thanks for your comment. I will experiment some more using other sorts combined with distance.